# How to deal with deadlock in MPI_Sendrecv in parallel programming?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to exchange data between neighboring processors. When using mpi_sendrecv to solve the problem, I got a deadlock.

I'm doing a parallel odd-even transposition sort. But in this case, I have to do odd even sort in each processor and compare left over numbers between neighboring processor.

```
if (num_elements_proc % 2 == 0) {

            int recv_num_1;
            int recv_num_2;
            int send_num_1;
            int send_num_2;
            MPI_Status status;
            // Perform Bubble sort on odd indexed element 
            for (int i = 1; i <= num_elements_proc - 2; i = i + 2) 
            { 
                if (sub_nums[i] > sub_nums[i+1]) {  
                    swap(sub_nums[i], sub_nums[i+1]); 
                    isSorted = false; 
                }

                send_num_1 = sub_nums[0];
                if (rank == root) {
                    MPI_Sendrecv(&send_num_1, 1, MPI_INT, m - 1, 1, &recv_num_1, 1, MPI_INT, m - 1, 1, comm, &status);
                } else {
                    MPI_Sendrecv(&send_num_1, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 1, &recv_num_1, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 1, comm, &status);
                }
                if (recv_num_1 > send_num_1) {
                    sub_nums[0] = recv_num_1;
                    isSorted = false;
                }
                send_num_2 = sub_nums[num_elements_proc-1];
                if (rank == m - 1) {
                    MPI_Sendrecv(&send_num_2, 1, MPI_INT, root, 1, &recv_num_2, 1, MPI_INT, root, 1, comm, &status);
                } else {
                    MPI_Sendrecv(&send_num_2, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 1, &recv_num_2, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 1, comm,&status);
                }
                if (send_num_2 > recv_num_2) {
                    sub_nums[num_elements_proc-1] = recv_num_2;
                    isSorted = false;
                }
            }

            // Perform Bubble sort on even indexed element 
            for (int i = 0; i <= num_elements_proc - 2; i = i + 2) 
            { 
                if (sub_nums[i] > sub_nums[i+1]) 
                { 
                    swap(sub_nums[i], sub_nums[i+1]); 
                    isSorted = false; 
                } 
            }
```

Comment: the easiest option is to post all your `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()` and then issue a single `MPI_Waitall()`. An other option (it it is a fit here) is to use `MPI_Neighbor_alltoall()`

Comment: Thank you Gilles! Now I will try your first suggestion. Although I haven't learn open mpi, I may take a look at MPI_Nrighbor_alltoall().